# Why did Miche choose to run away when there were Titans remaining?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In episode 1 of Attack on Titan 2,

> Miche managed to use himself as bait and killed most of the titans. **What is the point of running away knowing that Titans can sprint and could possibly catch up with his horse?** And the presence of the abnormal monkey-like Titan would make the situation more dangerous and unpredictable if I was him and I wanted to run away.
>
>  Edit: As he is the second-most skilled after Levi, he should have just killed all the Titans in his presence except the abnormal one without hesitation. Then even if the abnormal Titan had thrown the horse towards him he would not need to suffer a painful death.

Comment: During the scene you are referring to, there is considerable time pressure (hence why they did not engage all the titans, and instead chose to ignore them), and secondly, they are **surprised** about the Titans suddenly sprinting. Regardless of whether it was known that Titans can sprint, it was _unexpected_ for them to do so at this time. That can be a mistake on the humans' part; but it was their expectation nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the anime leaves out some of the finer details, which doesn't appear to make a difference in the long run, but ultimately leads to a lack of understanding about what has taken place and why.

Episode 2 of Season 2 of Attack on Titan directly corresponds to chapter 35 of the manga. Spoilers below.

> First, his primary objective was to notify others of the breach at Wall Rose and evacuate settlements. This outweighed any immediate danger presented in the situation and it represents WHY he chose to leave the area with titans still present. Now as for how he thought he could navigate the situation safely, Miche/Mike was known for his skills and prowess in battle, as mentioned in chapter 35 of Attack on Titan (manga). He truly thought himself to be capable of outmaneuvering, or outright defeating, the titans he had not yet dispatched. And, lastly, remember that horses at that time were specifically bred for speed and temperament for the sole purpose of successfully outrunning titans.

Comment: If the horses can successfully outrun Titans even in case they sprint, soldiers don't need to fear and Miche does not even need to use himself as bait to attract Titans in the first place.

Comment: If you watch the first episode you will know. People feared even just **normal Titans** began to sprint, doubting if their horses could successfully outrun them. Eventually Miche had to leave the formation to attract running Titans so he could ensure people's safety.

Comment: I thought of countering the response, but I don't want to get into an elaborate discussion about the obviously unrealistic science behind AoT. If the horses could not outrun the titans, they would not be used outside of the walls. We've seen many times where scouts on horses outran and outmaneuvered the titans. I can think of one such instance when a crawler was chasing them outside of the walls in episode 17 and Sasha was able to keep pace ahead of the titan and outmaneuver it.

Comment: I think for clarification though, when I say outrun, I don't mean that the horses marathon sprint right past the titans. I mean that they are physically capable of out-running and out-maneuvering the titans outside of the walls. Maybe I should have been more clear in my original answer to avoid confusion.